# Do employers see your StackOverflow reputation score in the search results?

Tags: discussion, jobs

From what I can tell from the "Employer View" of my CV, all that appears is name, location, the personal statement snippet and favorite technologies.

Is it correct that no info about StackOverflow reputation shows up in the employer search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have associated your account, your SO user badge will appear in the search results.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to turn this off? I mean, since you can turn everything else on and off.

Answer (score 3):

Quite obviously this would only happen if you associated your accounts.

Comment: why the down votes?